# Editdamnpoll is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled

Tags: reactjs

I am getting this error

> Warning: Editdamnpoll is changing an uncontrolled input of type text
>   to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled
>   to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or
>   uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

Here's my code

```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Api from '../../utils/ApiManager';
import {Link} from 'react-router';

var pollId = 2;
var newVotesObj ={};

class Editdamnpoll extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
              this.state = {
                poll:{
                    pollquestion: 'ankur',
                    author: 'ankur',
                    responses: [1]
                },
                newresponses:[2]
        };

    }
    componentWillMount(){
        var urlWithId =this.props.location.pathname;
        var pollID = urlWithId.split('/').pop();
        console.log("here's the poll id",pollID)
        Api.get('/api/polls/' + pollID, null, (err, response) => {
            if(err){
                 alert("Error: " + err); 

            }
            else{

                var newobj = {pollquestion:response.message.pollquestion,author:response.message.author,responses:response.message.responses}
                this.setState({
                    poll:newobj

                });
                var newarr = this.state.poll.responses.map(function(i,index){
                    return i.response
                })
                var tochange = this.state.newresponses;
                this.setState({
                    newresponses:newarr
                })
                console.log("this is only array",this.state.newresponses);
                console.log("conventional responses",this.state.poll.responses)

            }

        });

    }
    editpoll(){
        Api.put('/api/polls/' + pollId, newVotesObj, (err, response) => {
            if (err) { 
                 console.log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(err)); 
                 return;
            }

            // Success so update the state with the correct scores
            /*

            var listLen = updatedList.responses.length;
            for (let i = 0; i < listLen; i++) {
                if (updatedList.responses[i]['response'] == selectedRadio)
                    updatedList.responses[i]['votes'] = totalVotes;
            }

            // Get doughnut to re-draw chart. (using a data store?)
            var votesSoFar = updatedList.responses.map(function(rv) { return rv.votes; });
            chartValues.datasets[0].data = votesSoFar
            this.setState({ 
              data: chartValues,
              list: updatedList
            });

            */

        },true);


    }

    valuechangetext(e){
        console.log("this is the id",e.target.id)
        var key = e.target.id;
        var newresponses = this.state.newresponses[key];

       this.setState({
           newresponses:e.target.value

       })

    }







    render(){
        console.log("state",this.state)
        console.log("this map",this.state.poll.responses)
        var newarr = this.state.newresponses;
       var responseinput =  this.state.poll.responses.map(function(i, index){
           return(

               <div key={index} >

           <input type="text" id={index} onChange={this.valuechangetext.bind(this)} value={this.state.newresponses[index]} /> <br /><br />
           </div>
               )

        }.bind(this));
        console.log("response input inside render",responseinput)

        return (
            <div>
            <h2>Edit the damn poll here!!</h2>
            <h4>{this.state.pollquestion}</h4>
            <p>author:{this.state.author}</p>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleedit}>
            {responseinput}
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" name="submitBtn"  value="Submit Edited Poll"/>
             </form>
            <button onClick={this.editpoll.bind(this)}>Edit Poll</button>
            <Link to="/">Back</Link>
            </div>

        )
    }

}

export default Editdamnpoll
```

```

**My research till now on this matter**

I looked at stackoverflow questions. Every answer suggest me that I should initiate state's key value pair with "" . If it is null or undefined, react initiate it as uncontrolled component. When i am setting its value to this.state... . React thinks, I am changing uncontrolled component to controlled. But, as you can see right now, I initiated all states with some value. So, I am clueless why I still see this warning message?

Answer (score 1):

On first render `this.state.newresponses[index]` will be looking for `this.state.newresponses[0]` (from the index of the first `this.state.poll.responses` loop)

This doesn't exist yet, you have `this.state.newresponses = [2]`

You could change the initial state, or do something like this

`value={this.state.newresponses[index] || ''}`

Comment: Thanks. You are awesome. It worked!! Did you use react dev tools or its experienced eyes? I also tried to upvote your answer. But I got message that my vote has been recorded, but it will not be publicly displayed as  I have less reputation.

Comment: Iam trying to understand your answer. Inititally I do have this.state.newresponses=[2] , so when its looking for this.state.newresponses[0] . Than there is 2 there. Why it is throwing error? @mitchell